Evaluating $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{3n-\sqrt{9n^2+3n+1}}{\sqrt{n^2+5n+4}-n}$
I have a problem with solving this limit:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{3n-\sqrt{9n^2+3n+1}}{\sqrt{n^2+5n+4}-n}$$
So far i have tried $3n$ out of the square root as follows:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{3n-3n\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{3n}+\frac{1}{9n^2}}}{n\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{n}+\frac{4}{n^2}}-n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{3(1-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{3n}})}{\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{n}}-1}$$
When cancelling out the $\frac{1}{3n}$ and $\frac{5}{n}$ because they approach to 0 i get $[\frac{0}{0}]$. Finally I tried to substitute $u=\frac{1}{n}$ but that didn't get me anywhere. Can anyone help?

Taking it from where you are, you can use $\frac{(1+\alpha(n))^k-1}{\alpha(n)} \to k$, whenever $\alpha(n)\to 0$.

Your problem is that you drop of second order terms which would lead to a definite form for the limit.

@Nicolas the "second order" term is not relevant.

I am not allowed to use neither L'Hopital nor Taylor expressions, @SineoftheTime

Complete the squares...

We can proceed as follows
\begin{align}\frac{3n-\sqrt{9n^2+3n+1}}{\sqrt{n^2+5n+4}-n}&=\frac{3n-\sqrt{9n^2+3n+1}}{\sqrt{n^2+5n+4}-n}\frac{3n+\sqrt{9n^2+3n+1}}{\sqrt{n^2+5n+4}+n}\frac{\sqrt{n^2+5n+4}+n}{3n+\sqrt{9n^2+3n+1}}\\
&=\frac{-3n-1}{5n+4}\frac{\sqrt{n^2+5n+4}+n}{3n+\sqrt{9n^2+3n+1}}\end{align}
and then conclude as your first idea for each factor.

This is the best way. I don't know why my way is accepted answer now.

Could you elaborate on why this works?

Now, we use only factoring and limit rules to reach the answer. No approximations or squeeze theorem are needed.

@BobDobbs All solutions are very good! This one uses just an elementary approach! Thanks

@Mononika As Bob noticed, by factoring we obtain $-\frac35$ from the first factor and $\frac13$ from the second one.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{3n-\sqrt{9n^2+3n+1}}{\sqrt{n^2+5n+4}-n}=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{3n-\sqrt{(3n+\tfrac12)^2+\tfrac34}}{\sqrt{(n+\tfrac52)^2-\tfrac94}-n}
=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{3n-(3n+\tfrac12)}{(n+\tfrac52)-n}
=-\frac15
$$

First thing you should do is plug it in!
Everything of format $\frac{x}{n^p}$ where $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p\in \mathbb{N}$ is automatically approaching $0$ when $n\to \infty$.
So in your last step after cancelling out all of those terms in format I just mentioned, what are you left with?
$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{3-3\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{1}-1}$. You can notice how both of these are equal to $0$ so this is known as 'indeterminate form' $\frac{0}{0}$ and can't be solved in a regular way.
In this particular example, solving by approximating the expansion of the square roots is much faster than L'Hôpital's rule as that one leads into very complicated 2nd derivative expression.
Simplify the numerator: $3n-\sqrt{9n^2+3n+1} = n(3-\sqrt{9+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}})$
Approximate $\sqrt{1+x} \approx 1+ \frac{x}{2}$ for a small $x$
$\sqrt{9+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}} = 3+ \frac{\frac{3}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}{6} = 3n+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6n}$
Finally it becomes $3n-(3n++\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6n}) = -\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{6n}$
Similar process for denominator:
$\sqrt{n^2+5n+4}-n$
$\sqrt{n^2+5n+4} \approx n(1+\frac{5}{2n}+\frac{2}{n^2} = n + \frac{5}{2}+\frac{2}{n}$
After simplifying, denominator is $\frac{5}{2}+\frac{2}{n}$
Now combine numerator and denominator to solve:
$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{6n}}{\frac{5}{2}+\frac{2}{n}} \approx \frac{-\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{5}{2}} = -\frac{1}{5}$.

This is incorrect.  For one thing, $\sqrt{9+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}} = n(3+\frac{3\over n}{6} + o(\frac{1}{n^2}) = 3n+\frac{1}{2} + o(\frac{1}{n})$  is wrong

@J.W.Tanner Thank you for noticing, fixed the error.

Now you got the right answer, but still $\sqrt{9+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}} = 3+ \frac{\frac{3}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}{6} = 3n+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6n}$  is wrong

OP is not allowed to use Taylor

Last line should be $$ \lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{6n}}{\frac{5}{2}+\frac{2}{n}}= \frac{-\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{5}{2}} = -\frac{1}{5}$$

@user I understand but $\frac{1}{6n} \approx 0$ when $n\to \infty$ and similarly for $\frac{2}{n}$. It's approximated to be $0$ but it's never exactly $0$ hence why I used that notation.

@SineoftheTime I have just noticed it in the comments but it wasn't stated anywhere in the question (LH at least had a tag to not do it that way).

@DaniloJonić $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac 1n =0$ and not $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac 1n \approx 0$, this second way is a completely meaningless notation according to the definition of limit.

One simplification worth remembering is that $$\lim_{x\to 0} (1+x)^n = 1 + nx + o(x^2)$$
which is just taking first 2 terms from Newton binomial (but generalizes to any power)
When n=1/2, it applies to sqrt
$\sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{3n}}$ becomes $1 - \frac{1}{6n}$, and so on - making the rest of solution elementary

I will also proceed according to the @user's answer but my process is very slightly different from the accepted one.
Let's assume that $$L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{3n-\sqrt{9n^{2}+3n+1}}{\sqrt{n^{2}+5n+4}-n}$$
Let's divide the numerator and denominator by $n$.
$\implies L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{3n-\sqrt{9n^{2}+3n+1}}{n}}{\frac{\sqrt{n^{2}+5n+4}-n}{n}}$
$\implies L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{3-\frac{\sqrt{9n^{2}+3n+1}}{n}}{\frac{\sqrt{n^{2}+5n+4}}{n}-1}$
Now I will write $n=\sqrt{n^{2}}$
$\implies L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{3-\frac{\sqrt{9n^{2}+3n+1}}{\sqrt{n^{2}}}}{\frac{\sqrt{n^{2}+5n+4}}{\sqrt{n^{2}}}-1}$
$\implies L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{3-\sqrt{9+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{1}{n^{2}}}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{n}+\frac{4}{n^{2}}}-1}$
Now I will follow the @user's process.
That is at first I will multiply the numerator and denominator by $\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{n}+\frac{4}{n^{2}}}+1\right)$
$\implies L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\left(3-\sqrt{9+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{1}{n^{2}}}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{n}+\frac{4}{n^{2}}}-1\right)}×\frac{\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{n}+\frac{4}{n^{2}}}+1\right)}{\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{n}+\frac{4}{n^{2}}}+1\right)}$
$\implies L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\left(3-\sqrt{9+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{1}{n^{2}}}\right)\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{n}+\frac{4}{n^{2}}}+1\right)}{\left(\frac{5}{n}+\frac{4}{n^{2}}\right)}$
Now at $n\to \infty$, $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{n}+\frac{4}{n^{2}}}+1\right)=2$
Therefore the limit is becoming
$L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2\left(3-\sqrt{9+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{1}{n^{2}}}\right)}{\left(\frac{5}{n}+\frac{4}{n^{2}}\right)}$
Now again I will multiply the numerator and denominator by $\left(3+\sqrt{9+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{1}{n^{2}}}\right)$
Finally the limit becomes
$L=\lim_{n\to \infty}-\frac{2\left(\frac{3}{n}+\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)}{\left(\frac{5}{n}+\frac{4}{n^{2}}\right)\left(3+\sqrt{9+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{1}{n^{2}}}\right)}$
Now again $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(3+\sqrt{9+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{1}{n^{2}}}\right)=6$
Finally let's come to the answer.
After taking L.C.M. in the numerator and denominator we get the final limit to be :
$L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{-\left(\frac{3}{n}+\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)}{3\left(\frac{5}{n}+\frac{4}{n^{2}}\right)}$
$$\implies L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{-(3n+1)}{3(5n+4)}$$
Therefore $L=\frac{-1}{5}$
$\implies \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{3n-\sqrt{9n^{2}+3n+1}}{\sqrt{n^{2}+5n+4}-n}=\frac{-1}{5}$

Is the first step really necessary?

Why not @SineoftheTime ? I divided by $n$ and I wrote $n=\sqrt{n^{2}}$ to evaluate the limit

yeah I know but you're overcomplicating

Yes you are correct @SineoftheTime. But I solved this integral by explaining each and every step for OP to understand.
